# Weird behavior when reloading cells containing textFields in dynamic tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a dynamic tableView with custom cells that each contain a textField and label. I want the following behavior:

---

A user taps the "Add" button, and the table inserts a cell at index 0, with the cell's textField becoming the first responder.

When the user finishes inputting data, the one-lined textField resigns as first responder and hides itself.

The cell's label then becomes visible, filled with the user input, and auto-resizes it's height to accommodate the input. The cell is resized at this time too.

---

I have code that does exactly this the first time a cell is added, but when more cells are added then it gets weird. The second added cell
s textField does not become first responder and is filled with the text from the previous textField. Subsequent added cells appear blank, except every 6 blank cells, the first cell's text shows up.

What's going on, and how can I fix this?

**Edit: Thanks to @Rayfleck, I have resolved the issue of the second added cell being filled with the text from the previous textField, but the second cell that gets added (and subsequent added cells) still isn't becoming first responder.**

Here's the demo showing this behavior:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
#define FONT_SIZE 16.0f
#define CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH 300.0f // This will change for different size!
#define CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN_WIDTH 10.0f
#define CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN_HEIGHT 20.0f

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *notesArray;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.notesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Testo 1", @"This is a long string of text to show how the cell resizes to fit a variable height label.", @"Testo 3", @"Testo 4", @"Testo 5", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (IBAction)addButtonTapped {

    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
    [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]]; // insert at first index

    [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:NO]; // go into edit mode so cell has label hidden and textField visible

    // do the insertion
    [self.notesArray insertObject:@"" atIndex:0]; // placeholder for when user starts typing
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:NO];
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]; // first table cell
    HC_NoteCell *cell = (HC_NoteCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];

    cell.noteTextField.hidden = YES;
    cell.noteLabel.text = cell.noteTextField.text;
    cell.noteLabel.hidden = NO;

    [self.notesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:cell.noteTextField.text];

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    // Need to reload rows so cell height can be recalculated
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return self.notesArray.count;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *text;
    text = [self.notesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN_WIDTH * 2), 20000.0f);

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:FONT_SIZE];
    NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                                forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attrsDictionary];

    CGRect paragraphRect = [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:constraint options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) context:nil];

    CGFloat height = MAX(paragraphRect.size.height, 22.0f);

    return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN_HEIGHT * 2);

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NoteCell";

    HC_NoteCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[HC_NoteCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (self.tableView.isEditing) {

        cell.noteLabel.hidden = YES;
        cell.noteTextField.hidden = NO;
        cell.noteTextField.delegate = self;

        [cell.noteTextField becomeFirstResponder];

    } else {

        cell.noteLabel.hidden = NO;
        cell.noteTextField.hidden = YES;
        cell.noteTextField.delegate = self;

        cell.noteLabel.text = [self.notesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reusing/dequeing cells, then in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you must set the new value for every subview of the cell, because it will probably contain the contents of the previous cell.

So `cell.noteLabel.text = nil;` in all cases, and then in your else case, set it's value from the array.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, that solves the issue of the second added cell being filled with the text from the previous textField, but that second added cell still isn't becoming first responder. Any ideas on why that is happening?

Comment: It sounds like a timing issue.  It seems a bit unorthodox to assign a first responder from within cellForRowAtIndexPath, because you might be assigning in another cell.  Put an NSLog with the indexPath right after you assign first responder.  Since this assignment should happen only once, is it possible to do that assignment from somewhere else that is not looping through all the cells?  Alternatively, you could invoke it on another thread after a very short delay, so it will happen on the next drawing cycle.

Comment: As to the first responder issue, I ended up adding a hidden textField directly to the VC and made it first responder on viewDidLoad, then made the desired cell the first responder in viewDidLoad. Thanks!